# XSLT - extract all text but last subsection

Tags: xslt

Looking to parse out a namespace from a full class name in xml.

Data example:

```
<results>
    <test-case name="Co.Module.Class.X">
</results>
```

End result (going to csv format):

    `,Co.Module.Class`

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
  <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
  <xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
  <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
FullTestName, Namespace
<xsl:apply-templates select="//test-case" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test-case">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
      <xsl:value-of select="function to go here for nameWithJustNamespace" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$break" />    
  </xsl:template>
```

I understand the process would need a last index of "." to be called once, yet I'm not finding XSLT to have that function.  How to best accomplish this?

Comment: I think you should give some more information like input data, xsl stylesheet, output and desired output, Minimum Complete Verifyable Example ... (MCVE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in pure XSLT 1.0, you need to call a named recursive template, e.g.:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/results">
    <xsl:call-template name="remove-last-token">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="test-case/@name"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="remove-last-token">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'.'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains(substring-after($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="remove-last-token">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: [Well, I guess not.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526503/xslt-family-tree/37526892#comment62562181_37526892)

Answer (score 0):

**This pure XSLT 1.0 transformation** (shorter, no conditional XSLT operations, single template):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="test-case[contains(@name, '.')]">
  <xsl:param name="pDotIndex" select="0"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vNextToken" 
        select="substring-before(substring(@name, $pDotIndex+1), '.')"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring('.', 2 - ($pDotIndex > 0)),$vNextToken)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vNewDotIndex" select="$pDotIndex+string-length($vNextToken)+1"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="self::node()[contains(substring(@name,$vNewDotIndex+1), '.')]">
     <xsl:with-param name="pDotIndex" select="$vNewDotIndex"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<results>
    <test-case name="Co.Module.Class.X"/>
</results>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
Co.Module.Class
```

---

**Part 2**

With a slight modification the following transformation produces the complete CSV:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="test-case[contains(@name, '.')]">
  <xsl:param name="pDotIndex" select="0"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vNextToken" 
        select="substring-before(substring(@name, $pDotIndex+1), '.')"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(',', 2 - (position() > 1)),
                                substring('.', 2 - ($pDotIndex > 0)),  $vNextToken)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="vNewDotIndex" select="$pDotIndex+string-length($vNextToken)+1"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="self::node()[contains(substring(@name,$vNewDotIndex+1), '.')]">
     <xsl:with-param name="pDotIndex" select="$vNewDotIndex"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<results>
    <test-case name="Co.Module.Class.X"/>
    <test-case name="Co2.Module2.Class2.Y"/>
    <test-case name="Co3.Module3.Class3.Z"/>
</results>
```

**the wanted, correct (CSV) result is produced**:

```
Co.Module.Class,Co2.Module2.Class2,Co3.Module3.Class3
```